# OpenVZ Local Network

Tags: centos6, local-area-network, openvz

I recently aquired 7 OpenVZ Virtual Private Servers for a load balanced website.

- 2 Load Balancers
- 3 Web Servers + MySQL API Server + MySQL Storage Server
- 2 Storage Servers (For PHP Sessions and Uploaded content)

Though, my problem is I only have public IPv4s to connect them with and no LAN Network.
So I was wondering if it's possible to connect them locally.
I've found the following posts:
http://openvz.org/Virtual_Ethernet_device
http://www.linuxweblog.com/blogs/sandip/20080814/bridge-networking-on-openvz-containers-using-veth-devices

I'm running on a 64 Bit CentOS 6.5

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if your provider also provides a separate network for this purpose. Otherwise just use the public IP addresses. Though in this case, if you use SSL you will have to pass it all the way through to your backend servers rather than terminating it at the load balancers, to ensure that other customers' virtual machines cannot sniff your traffic. You'll also have to encrypt your MySQL connections and the connections to your storage servers...You may as well just set up a VPN between all your boxes.